# How to output the name and the price from an array?

Tags: php

Hello guys,                                                                               I would like to output only the name of each product side by side with the price of that product.
I don't want to output the ID or something else.

```
 <?php
     $a = array(
    array('id' => '1', 'name' => 'Milch','price' => '12'),
    array('id' => '2', 'name' => 'Reis','price' => '13'),
    array('id' => '3', 'name' => 'Öl','price' => '14'),
    array('id' => '4', 'name' => 'Salz','price' => '15'),
    array('id' => '5', 'name' => 'Zucker','price' => '16'),     
         );
        foreach ($a as $key => $value){
                print_r($a[$key]);
           }
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($a as $product) {
   echo $product['name'] . ': $' . $product['price'] . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Though really, there isn't a whole lot more to say here…

Comment: yes I know.. but what could you explain for such an easy example? this is the basics of handling arrays and displaying their data..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?

    $a = array(
    array('id' => '1', 'name' => 'Milch','price' => '12'),
    array('id' => '2', 'name' => 'Reis','price' => '13'),
    array('id' => '3', 'name' => 'Öl','price' => '14'),
    array('id' => '4', 'name' => 'Salz','price' => '15'),
    array('id' => '5', 'name' => 'Zucker','price' => '16'),     
         );

    foreach ($a as $key => $value){
        echo ( $value['name'] . ' ' . $value['price'] . PHP_EOL );
    }

?>


php select.php 
Milch 12
Reis 13
Öl 14
Salz 15
Zucker 16
```